# Does ng-app wait for document.ready?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a small `ng-app`/`ng-controller` block inside a large HTML file. I thought `ng-app` would be triggered after its `div` is loaded but in my case it waits for `document.ready` event.

When does angular instantiate `ng-app`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it waits for DOM content to load.  See the diagram from this documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap.

[image]

You can wait for dom ready with `ready()`.

```
angular.module("Foo")
  .controller("Bar", function () {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't DOMContentLoaded the same as document.ready?